# Can I use jdk 7 for android with 1.6 compiler?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have both JDK7_u40 and JDK6_u45 installed in my computer, with windows 7, I am currently working with LibGDX to make a simple game for desktop and Android,

I would like to know, can set compiler in jdk7 to 1.6 and use it in android without problem or I should set environment variable to jdk6 to use for android.
I am using ADT bundle.

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Eclipse and Android Studio should default to 1.6 when you create a new android project, so you shouldn't need to do anything to get it working with JDK 7.

If for some reason it gives you issues you can change the Source and Bytecode versions by going to "Project Properties" -> "Java Compiler"

Comment: when i create a new java project (not android) with ADT in library it seems that "JRE System Library [1.7]" so it uses 1.7, for example LibGDX creates project but it in ADT shows 1.7, **how can I set currect environment? or should I use jdk7 with its 1.6 compiler?**

Comment: If you use the JDK compiler you can build with Java 7, it's just the ADK that is hard coded to only allow up to 1.6. I was using 7 for awhile but had to switch back because there are complications with signing and using gradle in AS.

Answer (score 1):

rumors say only inteliJ supports java 1.7 (and maybe even java 1.8) coding for android, but i've never tested it.

the rest of the IDEs (that I know of) don't.

Comment: So you suggest that I use JDK 6 environment without jdk7's 1.6 compiler?

Answer (score 1):

staring with the ADT (22.6 ) and if your app has a minSdk of at least 19 (kitkat) , it should be possible to safely use java 1.7 functionalities :

http://tools.android.com/recent/eclipseadt226preview

Comment: sadly it will take a long time till developers would consider making apps that are supported only from kitkat and above...